# Glue job throwing AccessDeniedException eventhough IAM role has GetJob access added

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-glue

GlueJobRunnerSession is not authorized to perform: glue:GetJob on resource

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to determine the issue without having more details about your specific scenario. Either not all permissions are correctly set, or there is another policy in place that overrides the permissions.

In order to troubleshoot this yourself, you can use the [AWS IAM Policy Simulator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html) to test and find out if the permissions are set and if there are conflicting policies interfering.